# Run 2 containers in 1 spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux

Here're my case:

1. I'll use webflux starter and the default reactor netty server to serve my webflux app via 8080.
2. I'll use an embedded tomcat to serve my internal admin app  which is servlet based, say on 7070.

Does spring boot support this by simply applying some properties settings?

I just checked:

If I have both starter-webflux and starter-tomcat, the tomcat will win at 8080.

If I change server.port = 7070, tomcat will start at 7070 and netty is still ignored.

Thanks

Leon

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear, what is it that you want to achieve?

Comment: I just edit my question to be simpler, could you help to check it again?